# SQL - Seleccionar el último registro de cada empleado

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

necesito obtener el último registro de cada empleado de la tabla `entrada_empleado` donde se registra la hora de entrada de cada uno de ellos, la tabla esta normalizada por efecto de ejemplo lo he dejado como se muestra en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado con lo basico haciendo un

```
SELECT * FROM entrada_empleado LIMIT 1
```

evidentemente esta consulta solo me retorna el ultimo valor es decir el registro 10 y necesito en este otro formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se lo agradecería mucho si me orientaran como hacer este tipo de consulta

Comment: Deberías taggear solo el motor de base de datos en el cual vas a ejecutar la query.

Comment: perdón, voy a eliminar los que no voy a ocupar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esta consulta suponiendo que la siguiente es tu tabla:

**Tabla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(E.name) AS nombre,
(SELECT EE.hora_entrada
FROM entrada_empleado AS EE
WHERE EE.name = E.name ORDER BY EE.id DESC
LIMIT 1) AS hora
FROM entrada_empleado AS E;
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De esta forma mostraría el valor más alto de la hora no el último registro de la persona

Comment: MR Dev Creo que tu comentario esta equivocando, deberías revisar mejor el resultado con respecto a los  datos de la tabla, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es para postgresql (no me había dado cuenta que taggeaste tantos RDBMS):

Lo puedes hacer así, ordenas por nombre_empleado y id descendente, y utilizas la cláusla DISTINCT ON sobre nombre_empleado. De esta manera te traerá la información del último registro de cada empleado (entendiendo por el último el de  mayor id).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (nombre_empleado) *
FROM entrada_empleado
ORDER BY nombre_empleado, id DESC;
```

SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ): mantiene solo la primera fila de cada conjunto de filas donde las expresiones dadas se evalúan como iguales.

Esta opción utilizando window functions sirve tanto para MySql como para Postgresql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre_empleado ORDER BY id DESC) AS id,
      nombre_empleado,
      FIRST_VALUE(hora_entrada) OVER (PARTITION BY nombre_empleado ORDER BY id DESC) AS hora_entrada
FROM entrada_empleado
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Es una buena opción, para ser más precisa la consulta sería agregar el id de la persona en el `DISTINCT`

Comment: @MRDev no hay ningún id de persona, me baso en el modelo publicado en la pregunta.

Comment: Claro, es una recomendación para el autor

Comment: @MrDev deberías comentar la pregunta entonces,  no la respuesta.