# Como puedo obtener la fecha máxima para todos los datos de la tabla

Tags: sql, date, registro, maxima, teradata

Necesito obtener la fecha máxima de uso para cliente que tiene más de un producto en uso.

El dato de fecha máxima lo necesito a nivel cliente.

Lo que me trae el select que estoy ejecutando es lo siguiente:

```
select Cliente_id, producto_id, MAX(Fecha_Ult_Movimiento_Id) Fecha_maxima
from lk_Contratos a group by 1,2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesitaría que me devuelva la consulta es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Muchas gracias

Comment: Te falta poner la imagen, formula bien la pregunta para que sea mejor recibida y puedan ayudarte mas facil

Comment: No tenias que borrar la publicación anterior...

Comment: No lo sabia, por eso cree una nueva

Comment: A todos nos pasa una vez, pero es para que lo sepas. La prox solo espera su reapertura ;)

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos estás utilizando?

Comment: @Romina está [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/470475/218615) resuelve justamente tu problema, pero la solución puede ser diferente de acuerdo a la base de datos que estés usando y la versión de la misma. Si necesitas ayuda para adaptarla avisame.

Comment: Hola @nachospiu estoy utilizando teradata, me podrás ayudar a adaptarla?

Comment: Hola @Romina, no estoy familiarizado con Terada, pero ahí agregué una respuesta que creo te puede servir (en función de lo que leí), sino avisame y lo vemos.

Comment: Gracias @nachospiu pero se me va por spool la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Si agrupas por Cliente_id y por producto_id entonces la salida de la consulta va a ser igual a tu tabla inicial debido a que producto_id no se repite por Cliente_id, si miramos cada Cliente_id por separado vemos que no tiene productos repetidos, si lo que quieres  es obtener la fecha máxima por cliente entonces tu consulta seria:

```
SELECT Cliente_id, producto_id, MAX(fecha_movimiento) Fecha_maxima from lk_Contratos GROUP BY 1
```

Pero si lo que quieres es la fecha máxima por cada producto distinto de cada cliente entonces tu consulta seria:

```
SELECT Cliente_id, producto_id, MAX(fecha_movimiento) Fecha_maxima from lk_Contratos GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Hola Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta. La primera alternativa la probe pero me da error en el group by (Selected non-agreggate values)

Comment: Estoy usando Teradata. Por otro lado comentarte que un cliente_id si puede tener más de un producto. La segunda tabla la puse a nodo de ejemplo para que puedan ver que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy familiarizado con Teradata, pero creo que esta query utilizando  Window Functions te puede servir:

Trae para cada cliente la última fecha y el producto que se corresponde con esa fecha.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cliente_id, 
                first_value(producto_id) OVER (PARTITION BY Cliente_id ORDER BY Fecha_Ult_Movimiento_Id DESC) AS product_id, 
                first_value(Fecha_Ult_Movimiento_Id) OVER (PARTITION BY Cliente_id ORDER BY Fecha_Ult_Movimiento_Id DESC) AS Fecha_maxima
FROM lk_Contratos;
```